# Support : How can I investigate site analytics?

Tags: support

Is it possible to know site analytics such as percentage of unanswered questions, percentage of accepted answers, etc?

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/113651/what-percentage-of-questions-are-answered-on-stackoverflow-com